# Sort a map in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, hashmap, printf

I have a `map` with a number attached to an `alphabet`. The `map` is sorted by default using first value but I want to sort it by `frequency` i.e second value and then print it. Please help me do that
Edit:: There is nothing I can try here

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Dump the map into a `vector<pair<key_t, value_t>>`, sort it and print.

Comment: @MohitJain Can you please elaborate it a bit?

Answer (score 3):

You can't sort `map` directly according to its second value. But, it can be done manually. First, save the data of the `map` into a `vector` of `pair`, and then sort the vector according to your need.

But anyways here is a little code snippet to perform the above explained operation:

```cpp
template <typename T1, typename T2> struct less_second {
    typedef pair<T1, T2> type;
    bool operator ()(type const& a, type const& b) const {
        return a.second < b.second;
    }
};

map<key_t, value_t> mymap; /* It is map you want to sort according to the second argument*/
/* ...
   ...
   ...  */

vector<pair<key_t, value_t> > mapcopy(mymap.begin(), mymap.end());
sort(mapcopy.begin(), mapcopy.end(), less_second<key_t, value_t>());
```

Now, `mapcopy` *(it is a vector)* has your desired output.